# Error in generating MD5 for Google API key with Window 7 Ultimate

Tags: android, windows, google-maps, windows-7, md5

Here this is my cdm command .how  can i generate.  THe Google api key  in the command where is my error

```
C:\Users\DON>keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\DON\
.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
'keytool.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is that you're trying to use `Keytool` from the wrong location.place yourself under

```
c:\android_SDK_location\platform-tools\
```

or

```
c:\program files\java\jdk_location\jre\bin
```

and then execute `keytool`

Comment: hello sir thax u .can you add me on email rishigautamg@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

You need to navigate to your JRE folder (for example: `cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre7\bin"`).

After you have navigated, run the command:

```
keytool.exe -list -v -alias androiddebugkey -keystore C:\Users\DON\
.android\debug.keystore -storepass android -keypass android
```

Answer (score 0):

First go on command

```
Windows 7: C:\Users\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
Windows XP: C:\Documents and Settings\<user>\.android\debug.keystore
OS X and Linux: ~/.android/debug.keystore
```

then

keytool -list -alias androiddebugkey -keystore .keystore -storepass android -keypass android